# Why isn't the correct sprite showing after link has been visited?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

**DETAILS**

I'm trying to use a sprite image for a link. link,hover and active work, but visited doesn't. After a link has been visited it just returns to the original sprite. The CSS and HTML I am using is shown below.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#1" class="sprite favourite"> </a>    
<a name="1">link1</a>
```

**CSS**

```
 .sprite
    {
        width:15px;
        height:15px;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:block;
        background-image:url(everything-spritev2.png);
    }

.favourite:link{background-position:-32px 0;}
.favourite:hover{background-position:-48px 0;}
.favourite:visited {background-position:-64px 0;}  /* visited link */
.favourite:active {background-position:-64px 0;}
```

**QUESTION**

Why isn't the sprite for .favourite:visited working after the link has been clicked?

Comment: Try `.sprite.favourite:visited {background-position:-64px 0;}`, may be its specificity problem

Comment: I tried it but not luck.

Comment: Can you show me the issue, may be from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Yep sure. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/uB4db/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `:visited` style using background image has been disabled in Firefox due to privacy reason. This [page's note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3avisited#Summary) describes why, and this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector) describe the details. Other browsers may not have its `:visited` style disabled yet, but probably will in the future versions.

Possible workaround is to use script to track clicked links and the time in the local storage.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix it for me. I've put my original code at  jsfiddle.net/uB4db/2 if your interested in having a look.

Comment: I just got more info about Firefox. I was using Opera (it's still enabled), so I didn't know.

Comment: I probably can't style this with js either can I? I assume the browser will still block it.

Comment: You can still style a `SPAN` element independently that's inside the `A` element, the script handles which image to show based on the `A` element.

Comment: OK. I had a bit of a play, but I can't work it out. I think I will post it in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's mitigating the [CSS history attack](http://www.alanayoub.com/css-history-hack/).

[Preventing attacks on a user's history through CSS](http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy).

Comment: This would be great as a comment.. :)